# break says error: Jump target cannot cross function boundary. typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, break

for sure my logic in much more complicated but here is a placeholder code where I am trying to stop a recursive call but break keyword says `Jump target cannot cross function boundary .ts(1107)`

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

async function recCall(input: number[]) {

    if (input.length) {
        let eachItem = input.pop();

        // my logic includes http call with await

        recCall(input); // next iter
    }else{
        break; // says error 
    }
};
```

this is not plain javascript but typescript, my typescript version is:

`tsc -v 
 Version 3.7.5`

I am unable to understand what does this error means and why it is occuring, I searched on the internet but didn't found any reasons, I have been using break for breaking loops past years and now it is apparently started not working and saying an error I do not understand
any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Is there actually a loop you are breaking from?
Edit: see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a loop to break from. You are calling your function recursively, this is not the same as a loop. Use `return` instead of `break`:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

async function recCall(input: number[]) {

  if (input.length) {
    let eachItem = input.pop();

    // my logic includes http call with await

    recCall(input); // next iter
  }else{
    return;
  }
};
```

Comment: ohh yes, you arw right, I'm breaking loop but recursive call is ultimately is a function and break is not the keyword for breaking function but return

Comment: but still I would not say "how fools of me" rather typescript could have through a better error message for example `you can not use break for breaking function body did you mean return`

Comment: I went to github to open issue on non-sense error message but it looks like other people already have noticed this non-sense and talking on this, look: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30408

Comment: @InzamamMalik yeah beauty of programming. can you please mark the answer as accepted? cheers

Comment: I did, it takes 5 minutes actually before you can mark it accepted I came to know this fact just now